# C4267 warning when trying to send data over socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, warnings, winsock2

My program will only run on Windows machines. I got multiple warnings, all the same. This is the warning:

```
Warning C4267   'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

I get the warning when trying to send a string over a socket.

```
size_t ntohl_ch(char const* a)
{
    size_t x; memcpy(&x, a, sizeof(x));
    return ntohl(x);
}
size_t num = htonl(bufferSize); // bufferSize is also size_t

// Send buffer
    size_t totalSent = 0;
    size_t sent = 0;
    while (totalSent < bufferSize)
    {
        sent = send(ClientSocket, buffer + totalSent, bufferSize - totalSent, 0); // warning points to this line
        if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("error sending buffer %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return SOCKET_ERROR;
        }
        totalSent += sent;
    }
```

I know that `send()` return `int` and I can change `sent` and `totalSent` to int, but then inside `send()` I try to do operation like plus or minus on `int` and `size_t`. Like this: int - size_t. I don't think that's the right way to do it.

The warning doesn't show when I cast all the `size_t` parameters to `int` inside `send()`, but I think that's not the right way to do it because it can cause undefined behaviour. How can I solve this warning? Or can I just ignore it?

Comment: Unless you can have a buffer that's bigger than `INT_MAX` there's no problem.

Comment: Doesn't `send` return `ssize_t`, that is a signed type which gets set to -1 in case of errors? If I was a compiler, then that's what I would have warned about.

Comment: @Lundin The WinSock version returns int.

Comment: (its third argument is also an int)

Comment: `size_t num = htonl(bufferSize); // bufferSize is also size_t` seems to be superfluous as `num` is not used in the code fragment.  Indeed, the function `size_t ntohl_ch(char const* a)` function also seems to be unused and hence superfluous.

Comment: @EugeneSh. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-send

Comment: Oh, it's Windows... Ok, cleaning up my comments.

Comment: @Shawn It's apparently returning -1 no matter, so it's a bug no matter (but not the one the warning is about).

Comment: @Lundin the warning is about passing a `size_t` to a parameter that takes an `int`. I don't see anything about any function returning -1.

Comment: @Shawn It's in the manual: "Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned". This happens to expand to -1 on Windows as well.

Answer (score 1):

> *The warning doesn't show when I cast all the `size_t` parameters to `int` inside `send()`, but I think that's not the right way to do it
> because it can cause undefined behaviour. How can I solve this
> warning? Or can I just ignore it?*

There is only one parameter in the call to `send()` that you need to cast: the third. For that parameter, you are passing the result of the subtraction of one `size_t` from another, which will also be of `size_t` type.

However, as pointed out in the comments, so long as the resulting difference is less than `INT_MAX` (which seems likely, as that is `2147483647` on Windows), then you won't get any undefined behaviour from casting that result to an `int`. So, just cast the result of that subtraction to silence the warning.

**But note**: (as also pointed out in the comments), you also have an issue with the return value from that call. The `SOCKET_ERROR` constant is defined as `(-1)` in the "WinSock2.h" header, so testing an (unsigned) `size_t` value against that will, at best, confuse any future readers of your code<sup>1</sup>. It would be far better to have the `sent` variable declared as an `int`:

```c
int sent = send(ClientSocket, buffer + totalSent, (int)(bufferSize - totalSent), 0);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This "confusion" can arise from trying to remember what [the "usual arithmetic conversion" rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) are when having integral operands of different signedness for the `=` and `==` operators. In your case, the `size_t` has an rank greater than (64-bit build) or equal to (32-bit build) the `int` 'literal' (`-1`), so (from the above-linked cppreference page):

> If the unsigned type has conversion rank greater than or equal to the rank of the signed type, then the operand with the signed type is implicitly converted to the unsigned type.

… further confusion could ensue, when trying to remember what the rule is for converting a negative integer to an unsigned type.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an important warning. Are you sure there isn't another one just below it which points out the actual bug?

No matter if using sys/socket.h or winsock2.h, the `send` function returns -1 (`SOCKET_ERROR` == -1) upon errors, as foretold in the [Friendly Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send).

Therefore a correctly configured compiler such as gcc/mingw `-Wall -Wextra` tells you about this severe bug here `if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR)`:

> warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'size_t' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]|

Since `size_t` can never have the value `-1`, this is a bug. Don't compare unsigned integers against negative values.

---

Instead of the bug, your compiler is apparently whining about some irrelevant stuff like passing `size_t` instead of `int` to the parameters.

From the Friendly Manual:

```
int WSAAPI send(
  [in] SOCKET     s,
  [in] const char *buf,
  [in] int        len,
  [in] int        flags
);
```

So just use `int` instead of `size_t` as told in the manual and all your problems will go away.